# How to determine the hostname a locally running appengine instance is assigned to?

Tags: google-app-engine, hostname

I start an local instance of google app engine using this command line

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host localhost --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --admin_port 8081 .
```

Is there any GAE API that can let me retrieve the hostname (argument to the `--host` parameter, in this case `localhost`) I have passed to this the dev_appserver.py?

Comment: In Python you can use: os.environ["SERVER_NAME"]

Comment: It is the answer I am looking for. Can you turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using webapp2 on appengine you can access host property on the webapp2 request object.

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        host= self.request.host
```

https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes

Comment: It is the host from which the request originated from, right? It is not what I am asking

Comment: No. It is the host where the request is being handled. i.e. For an app running on localhost it will return localhost. If you app running on yourapp.appspot.com it will return yourapp.appspot.com